# wpf datepicker visibility binding dont work

Tags: wpf, binding, datepicker, visibility

I want to code in xaml all elements but by code-behind showing and hiding some parties depend on step.
here i modified code to been understendable so i putted both propriety to collapsed
question is about visibility of itemscontrol and datepicker cause second one never take value from codebehind

having this code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Name="d1">
        <ItemsControl Name="Panel" ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" Visibility="{Binding Panel_Visibility}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Height="100" Width="100" Margin="5" Content="{Binding Content}" Command="{Binding Button_Click}" CommandParameter="{Binding Content}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="d2">
        <DatePicker Name="DateVoyage" Visibility="{Binding DateVoyage_Visibility}"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

and having :

```
class Page_Modele : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    ...

    private Visibility panel_visibility;
    public Visibility Panel_Visibility {
        get { return this.panel_visibility; }
        set {
            this.panel_visibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Panel_Visibility");
        }
    }

    private Visibility datevoyage_visibility;
    public Visibility DateVoyage_Visibility {
        get { return this.datevoyage_visibility; }
        set {
            this.datevoyage_visibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DateVoyage_Visibility");
        }
    }

    ...

    public Page_Modele()
    {
        this._data = new donnees();
        Panel_Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        DateVoyage_Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.Content = itemsourc.Get_itemsourc(Execute1_ButtonClick, this._data.getContinentsList());

    }
    ...
}
```

ItemsControl is collapsed, but DatePicker not.
What i am missing?

Comment: Modify the binding as follows and watch the Visual Studio Output pane at runtime for diagnostic information: `Visibility="{Binding DateVoyage_Visibility, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`. Are there any items in the ItemsControl? I suspect it may not really be collapsed either.

Comment: i am sorry. I found my mistake... it wasnt been in code posted here... i assigned datacontext to panel, not to window so other elements doesnt seen changed visibility... sorry for spaming here

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it figured out.